# Native alike Input Design in Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I want to create following input design to be more Android native alike:

[image]

Is there any default way in JQM to have that design? I don't see any option from [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/forms/textinputs/).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to find it as a single component. There are few pure jQuery implementations, but they don't play well with jQuery Mobile.

Though there's another solution, you can use **nativeDroid2** jQuery Mobile theme which is built according to Google Material Design patterns.

http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/material/

Or you can find it here: http://www.gajotres.net/top-10-best-looking-free-jquery-mobile-themes/